# Removing Unwanted Spaces Using javascript

Tags: javascript, trim

In my application i want to remove the unwanted space from starting and ending.And also if there have more than space between words also remove them leaving one space.
How can i do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [trim in javascript ? what this code is doing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387088/trim-in-javascript-what-this-code-is-doing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
//remove leading spaces
content = content.replace(/^\s+/g,'');
//remove trailing spaces
content = content.replace(/\s+$/g,'');
//remove whitespaces in the middle
content = content.replace(/\s+/g,' ');
```

Comment: when i using this an error occurs "x.rep is undefined" x is my variable

Answer (score 1):

This should work to remove leading and trailing spaces, and reduce two or more spaces to a single space:

```
str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/, '').replace('/\s\s+/', ' ')
```

Comment: nah, removes only leading one

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery trim method.This function remove all new lines and all spaces leading or trailing from input string.

```
var str = '          it is a test string                ';

alert($.trim(str));
```