# Why is this regular expression so slow?

Tags: javascript, regex, performance

I am trying to trim leading and trailing whitespace and newlines from a string. The newlines are written as `\n` (two separate characters, slash and `n`). In other words, it is a string literal, not a CR LF special character.

For example, this:

`\n   \nRight after this is a perfectly valid newline:\nAnd here is the second line.    \n`

Should become this:

`Right after this is a perfectly valid newline:\nAnd here is the second line.`

I came up with this solution:

```
text = text
        .replace(/^(\s*(\\n)*)*/, '') // Beginning
        .replace(/(\s*(\\n)*)*$/, '') // End
```

These patterns match just fine according to [RegexPal](http://bit.ly/1aX9HUp).

However, the second pattern (matching the end of the string) takes a very long time — about 32 seconds in Chrome on a string with only a couple of paragraphs and a few trailing spaces. The first pattern is quite fast (milliseconds) on the same string.

[Here is a CodePen to demonstrate it](http://codepen.io/cpatik/pen/dkmel).

Why is it so slow? Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: Possible duplicate [trim in javascript ? what this code is doing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3387088/580951)

Comment: @Romoku I agree that the other question is on the same topic, but I don't see anything there about regex performance.

Comment: You have a huge deal of optionality, even nested optionality. That is very slow. Do `.replace(/^\s+/).replace(/\s+$/)`

Comment: Look up [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html). This is almost certainly the problem.

Comment: You don't need to write newline as `\\n` in a regex literal. If you do, then you're telling it to match a backslash character followed by the letter "n". Also, `\n` is matched by the special `\s` character class.

Comment: \s stands for "whitespace character". It includes [ \t\r\n]. That is: \s will match a space, a tab or a line break. You don't need to add the matches for "\n". Look at Esailija's comment.

Comment: He wants to match `\n` as a string literal, not a CR LF. That's what he spent the first three paragrahps explaining. This isn't catastrophic backtracking.

Comment: @Pointy That's exactly what I'm after -- a backslash followed by an 'n'. It is not a single (invisible) newline character. The pattern I posted does work, it's just slow.

Comment: Craig - just for the hell of it, try making your second regex `/(\s|\\n)+$/` and see if anything changes.

Comment: @Dan Yes it is, the actual characters you want to match is irrelevant, \s matches a great deal of different characters by itself already.

Comment: @craigpatik ah OK I understand.  Sorry for misunderstanding that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason it takes so long is because you have a `*` quantifying two more `*`

A good explanation can be found in the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.onlyonce.php), but I don't think JavaScript supports once-only subpatterns.

I would suggest this regex instead:

```
text = text.replace(/^(?:\s|\\n)+|(?:\s|\\n)+$/g,"");
```

Comment: That did it. Very quick, thank you. See the "Both, much faster" button in the pen: http://codepen.io/cpatik/pen/dkmel

Answer (score -3):

Not a good answer but one workaround would be to reverse the string and also reverse \n to n\ in the regular expression (for beginning), apply it, then reverse the string back.

Comment: overcomplicating the task... really