# .trim() Not Working in ie

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.trim() in JavaScript not working in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308134/trim-in-javascript-not-working-in-ie)

Is there any way to make .trim() work in Internet Explorer 6.

Comment: This question would be much easier to answer if you provided: 1) A **small** snippet of the code in question (no more than 5 lines); 2) The input to the code, if it's not obvious from the first part; 3) What output you *expected*; 4) What output you actually *observed*.  Right now it's just going to get closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this thread help you to make it work ? :
[.trim() in JavaScript not working in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308134/trim-in-javascript-not-working-in-ie)

At the end, look the message from kaichanvong regarding IE6

Answer (score 3):

make a custom function trim() for yourself

```
if (typeof String.prototype.trim !== 'function') {
  String.prototype.trim = function(s) {
     return s.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
  }
}
```