# are text.trim() really can't work in IE8

Tags: jquery

when i test my web-page in chrome and firefox they work fine. but in IE it does not worked.

i found that

`(" .class li").text().trim()` not worked in IE he give  me error that

Object doesn't support this property or method. but in FF and chrome they work fine. are i goes something wrong to handle this.

Comment: Please show some of the HTML you are applying this on

Comment: possible duplicate of [.trim() in JavaScript not working in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308134/trim-in-javascript-not-working-in-ie)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this:

```
$.trim($(".class li").text());
```

The reason that it doesn't worked in your case is because the trim method you were calling was wasn't [jquery.trim](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) method. It is a method you were calling on a object instance (`.text()` returns a string). So some browsers have this method built-in while IE doesn't.

Comment: Well then you will have to do the same everywhere in your code. Look at the jquery documentation of the $.trim function and you will see that it is used exactly like that. If you are still getting error messages it is not on this function.

Answer (score 1):

`String.trim` is not part of the old language specification, it is a new kid in town. Fortunetely you can easily add this function.

```
if (typeof String.prototype.trim != "function") {
  String.prototype.trim = function () {
    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
  };
}
```

Now you can trim any `String` you want:

```
" just do it   ".trim()
$(" .class li").text().trim()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove both leading and trailing spaces you need to use

```
replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '')
```

Comment: jQuery.trim(jQuery('#message').val());