# Javascript Trim as is in C#

Tags: javascript, jquery, trim

There is [JQuery.trim()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) function but it is trimming the white spaces.

But I want to do it like in C#.

```
string props = ",width=400,height=400,status=0,location=0,";
props.Trim(',');
// result will be: "width=400,height=400,status=0,location=0"
```

How can I do this? Actually I would like to use it for general input param not only for ','..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try an regexp:

```
var props=",width=400,height=400,status=0,location=0,";
props=props.replace(/^[,]*(.*?)[,]*$/, "$1");
```

If you, for example, also want to remove semicolons at the beginning or the end, use this:

```
props=props.replace(/^[,;]*(.*?)[,;]*$/, "$1");
```

And if you want to remove spaces, too, but only at the end:

```
props=props.replace(/^[,;]*(.*?)[,; ]*$/, "$1");
```

Answer (score 1):

I found [a link](http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-trim.html) do this with functions and I found [another link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308134/trim-in-javascript-not-working-in-ie) how to add this function to the String type. And I wrote below code and its [test link](http://jsfiddle.net/jsfiddleCem/hWPSB/) :

```
String.prototype.TrimLeft = function (chars) {
    //debugger;
    var re = chars ? new RegExp("^[" + chars + "]+/", "g")
                   : new RegExp(/^\s+/);
    return this.replace(re, "");
}
String.prototype.TrimRight = function (chars) {
    var re = chars ? new RegExp("[" + chars + "]+$/", "g")
                   : new RegExp(/\s+$/);
    return this.replace(re, "");
}
String.prototype.Trim = function (chars) {
    return this.TrimLeft(chars).TrimRight(chars);
}
```

`^[" + chars + "]+` is finding the characters at the begining of string. 
And it is replacing on this line: `this.replace(re, "");`

With this : `[" + chars + "]+$`, it is searching characters at the end of string `g`(globally) and replacing with the same method.

```
var c=",width=400,height=400,status=0,";
c.Trim(",");
// result: width=400,height=400,status=0
```

Comment: This will work, but there are powerful arguments to say that you shouldn't [modify objects you don't own](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/03/02/maintainable-javascript-dont-modify-objects-you-down-own/).

Comment: I didn't read it yet but I will. Thank your for your comment.