# Why does Internet Explorer not like this jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

While debugging some jQuery that is not working in IE, I found this error message:

```
var item = $("#item_"+ itemArray[itemIndex]).find('a').text().trim();

Object doesn't support this property or method (script.js, line 100, character 2)
```

The `character 2` doesn't make sense to me. Based on the text displayed `character 2` would be the letter `a` in `var` but of course that doesn't make any sense.

**(Should I not use `var`?)**

I know that jQuery is working to some extent or the script would not have been able to get this far on my page.

Comment: Why? Because it is Internet Explorer.

Comment: This has been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308134/trim-in-javascript-not-working-in-ie Basically, it looks like IE does not have `trim()` built-in.

Comment: possible duplicate of [.trim() in JavaScript not working in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308134/trim-in-javascript-not-working-in-ie)

Comment: @Stephen - That's a non-jQuery question, the optimal answer differs.

Answer (score 19):

IE doesn't have [`String.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim), you'll need [`$.trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) (which uses native trim if available, emulates it in IE), like this:

```
var item = $.trim($("#item_"+ itemArray[itemIndex]).find('a').text());
```

Comment: Be quick, Roger! Accept this as this question gets closed soon :') Nick's 115k isn't yet enough!

Comment: @Time - just to note it shouldn't be closed with *that* duplicate, there's a much easier work-around here than a non-jquery question (which is marked as the duplicate), which I've provided above :)

Comment: Aha, I see, it's not jQuery-related. (Y)

Comment: Potato Patata.  Well, not really.  Okay, you win.  ;)

Answer (score 3):

IE doesn't have a `trim` method.

Instead, you can call `jQuery.trim(...)`.