# Getting error while using .Val() in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using JQuery and I have got below JQuery Code sample.

**JQuery Code:**

```
 $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",
        url: "Login.aspx",  // Send the login info to this page
        data: str,  
        success: function(result)
        {  
             // Show 'Submit' Button
            $('#loginButton').show();

            // Hide Gif Spinning Rotator
            $('#ajaxloading').hide();  

            var resLength = (result).val().trim().length;
            alert(resLength);
            if(resLength!=0)
            {

                var arr = result.split(",");
                var fname = arr[0];
                var lname = arr[1];
                var activeCardNo = arr[2];
                var multipleTier = arr[3];
                var activeStatus = arr[4];
                var access = arr[5];
            }
        }
    });
```

In Above code sample when I am trying to use **.val()** in below line

```
var resLength = (result).val().trim().length;
```

it is giving error **"result.val is not a function"**, If I am using just **result.trim().length** its working fine in firefox, however giving error in IE.

Please suggest!

Comment: By the way - your code can be much cleaner if you used JSON instead of a comma separated string.

Comment: can you please suggest how can I use it, I have no Idea of JSONP..thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this:

```
var resLength = $.trim(result).length;
```

If `result` is a string, it doesn't have a `val` function. `trim` isn't supported cross-browser, so you should use [`jQuery.trim`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) instead.

Another option is checking the value directly. The empty string has a false value in JavaScript, so you can check:

```
result = $.trim(result);
if(result)
{
    // split, ...
}
```

If `result` is intended to be an element, you should wrap it in a jQuery object:

```
var resLength = $.trim($(result).val()).length;
```

Comment: very nice detailing of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is `result.trim().length` and IE doesn't support `trim()` (see [.trim() in JavaScript not working in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308134/trim-in-javascript-not-working-in-ie)) so it complains.

Try adding the accepted answer code from he linked question to your code and see if it fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

The code should be:-

```
var resLength = result.val().trim().length;
alert(resLength);
```

Writing "`(result)`" instead of "`result`" gives the error. This is because the variable here is the "`result`" itself.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I can't reproduce this, and can't think of a simple scenario where `( )` around a variable would make that difference.

Answer (score 0):

`(result).val();` this is wrong

the above one is used for input type html values

if the result is html please use

```
.text(); or .html()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a jQuery object, it's just a text value of the returned ajax