# Allow -(Negative) sign only once in text box using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a text box where I restrict user from typing anything other than numeric values. 
Only 0-9 allowed using jQuery.

My code:

```
if (event.which < 46 || event.which > 59)
event.preventDefault();
```

Now, I want to allow a negative sign (only at beginning) with numeric like `(-12,-13)`. I should restrict these scenarios `(--1,-1-,1----)`. Only valid negative numbers should be allowed.

How can I do this using jQuery?

Comment: See this link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544165/checking-if-value-of-a-textfield-is-integer-in-javascript . they give you methods to check for integers, which a negative number also is.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this validator: jquery.numeric

http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/numeric/

Comment: Why use a validator for such a small thing? What if the only thing the code needed to do was check for integers? Won't this be too much of an overhead ?

Comment: But adding a 40k js file for doing one operation. Isn't that bad? `:O`

Comment: @passionateCoder actually is 8kb, this have more validations (like ctrl+v) and even can be used in others sections in webpage. Always depende from user if can be useful

Comment: `did not know that `. Just read the docs. Nice :-) thanks for the enlightenment

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered... [not using jQuery for everything](http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif)?

```
<input type="number" step="1" />
```

This will allow the user to type anything they want, but supporting browsers (all of them if they're up-to-date) will prevent the form from being submitted if the value is not a valid number.

Unsupporting (out-of-date) browsers will submit the form regardless, but that's fine because 1) You should be validating server-side anyway, and 2) any jQuery solution would fail if the user disables JavaScript, whereas this *will* work without JS in supporting browsers.

Comment: Just out of curiosity.. Is the `step` attribute HTML 5 related?

Comment: Yes, it constrains the input to integers. [Docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.number.html)

Comment: It looks like "number" isn't supported in Firefox, even the latest version, or IE below 10: http://caniuse.com/input-number

Comment: @JoshNoe Like I said, that's fine because validation should always be done server-side.

Comment: @Kolink Server-side validation, while necessary, should be a fall-back behind client-side feedback in this case.  I wouldn't want to give over half of my users (IE 9- and FF) a bad UX by making them wait until they submit to see this field doesn't accept non-numeric.

Comment: @JoshNoe Well it should be obvious from labels etc. that a field expects a number ;)