# Text Box Integer Validation

Tags: javascript, html, validation, text, integer

I need to create a code in HTML/Javascript that will allow a user to enter an answer to a maths question and then the site needs to validate whether that answer is correct.

Been playing around for a few hours and researched the web but not found anything close.

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: "Been playing around for a few hours" can you provide the code you've been playing around so that it is easy for the community to provide a relevant answer..?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `javascript` for validation,

Look at this example.

```
var value = Number(intfield.value);
if (Math.floor(value) == value) {
    // value is an integer, do something based on that
} else {
    // value is not an integer, show some validation error
}
```

[checking if value of a textfield is integer in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544165/checking-if-value-of-a-textfield-is-integer-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript validation

```
function isInteger(number) {
    var getVal = parseInt(number);
    if (number.length == 0 || getVal == Number.NaN || getVal <= 0) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```