# jQuery error only in IE (8) - "Object doesn't support..."

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-maps, internet-explorer-8

I have this snippet of code (AJAX) in jQuery.

```
$.get('someScript.php?lat=' + clickedLatLng.lat() + '&lon=' + clickedLatLng.lng() + '&value=5', doSomething);
```

And this is a function (shows an icon on Google Maps and changes some values in input fields).

```
function doSomething(data) {
    data = data.trim();
    data = data.split(","); 
    var stopName = data[0];
    var stopLat = data[1];
    var stopLon = data[2];

    $("#start").val(stopName);

    if (startMarker == null) {
        startMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: new google.maps.LatLng(stopLat,stopLon),
                            map: map,
                            zIndex: 2,
                            title: stopName,
                            icon: startImage 
        });
    } else {
        startMarker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(stopLat,stopLon));
    }
}
```

But it works in all browsers except IE, in my case IE 8. I didn't test it in IE 6/7. It pops out this error...

[image: jquery error in IE 8]

I looked into **jquery.js** and this is the function where it breaks...

```
            // resolve with given context and args
            resolveWith: function( context, args ) {
                if ( !cancelled && !fired && !firing ) {
                    firing = 1;
                    try {
                        while( callbacks[ 0 ] ) {
                            callbacks.shift().apply( context, args );
                        }
                    }
                    finally {
                        fired = [ context, args ];
                        firing = 0;
                    }
                }
                return this;
            },
```

actually

```
callbacks.shift().apply( context, args );
```

Can someone help? Where is the problem? The same thing with **jquery-1.4.4.js**

**EDIT:** This is my larger code...

```
    // Set some events on the context menu links
contextMenu.find('a').click( function()
{
    // fade out the menu
    contextMenu.fadeOut(75);

    // The link's href minus the #
    var action = $(this).attr('href').substr(1);

    switch (action) {
        case 'startMenu':
            $.get('someScript.php?lat=' + clickedLatLng.lat() + '&lon=' + clickedLatLng.lng() + '&radijus=5', doSomethingWithData1);
            break;

        case 'stopMenu':
            $.get('someScript.php?lat=' + clickedLatLng.lat() + '&lon=' + clickedLatLng.lng() + '&radijus=5', doSomethingWithData2);    
            break;
    }

    return false;
});
```

When user clicks on an item within **context menu** on Google Maps then do "**doSomethingWithData1**" and "**doSomethingWithData2**". This is also some code for context menu

```
    // Hover events for effect
contextMenu.find('a').hover( function() {
    $(this).parent().addClass('hover');
}, function() {
    $(this).parent().removeClass('hover');
});
```

and this for **AJAX**

```
$.ajaxSetup ({  
        cache: false  
    });
```

This is how I included my **jQuery** scripts.

```
    <!-- Google Maps -->       
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

<!-- Load Javascript / jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.5.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.position.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery.ptTimeSelect.css" type="text/css" media="all" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jqtransformplugin/jquery.jqtransform.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jqtransformplugin/jqtransform.css" type="text/css" media="all" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
```

Comment: If you're getting an error in the `jquery.js` file, 99.9999% of the time, it's a problem with **your** code. Looking into it.

Comment: Can you provide how you're referencing jQuery.js in your HTML markup?

Comment: Also, do you get the error on the loading of the page?...or in your callback function?  Is your callback actually getting called?

Comment: I'd recommend setting a breakpoint on the first line of your `setPosition` callback and single-stepping through it. Look at the resulting `data` and make sure it makes sense. Find out what line of code is actually failing (the jQuery line you've quoted is just calling your callback; much more likely that the error is *in* the callback).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This was it =/ - [.trim() in JavaScript not working in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308134/trim-in-javascript-not-working-in-ie)

Solution - add this before you use .trim function.

```
if(typeof String.prototype.trim !== 'function') {
  String.prototype.trim = function() {
    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept your own answer so anyone coming to the question in the future will be able to see the solution at a glance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the variable callbacks is not an array somehow in this case. hence callbacks.shift() fails

As for the reason, Call me paranoid but try your code this way

```
var url = 'someScript.php?lat=' + clickedLatLng.lat() + '&lon=' + clickedLatLng.lng() + '&value=5';
$.get(url,function(data){
console.log(data);
});

//if the above worked then try this
$.get(url, doSomething);
```