# jQuery dialog buttons rebinding

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-dialog, jquery-ui-button

I have a simple jQuery dialog box that has an html input inside it. There are two buttons Save/Cancel on the dialog box. When the user hits Save, I validate if he has provided any input in the input box. If he hasn't, I report the error on a new line in the dialog box and wait for him to provide input. But when he hits Save again, nothing happens. How can I re-bind the Save button once it has been used? Thanks!

```
    var message = "Please provide Phone number."
    var phoneNum = "<input type='text' id='phoneNum' name='phoneNum'/> ";
    var dialogHtml = "<div id='confirmPhoneNumber'>"  + message + phoneNum + "<div id='dialogError' style='display:none'>Phone number field cannot be empty</div>" + "</div>";
    $(this).append(dialogHtml);
    $("#confirmPhoneNumber").css("font-size", "70%");
    $("#confirmPhoneNumber").dialog({
        resizable : false,
        modal : true,
        title : 'Save Phone',
        buttons : {
            'Save' : function () {
                // Phone number must be provided
                if ($("#phoneNum").val().trim().length == 0) {
                    $("#dialogError").show();
                } else {
                // Make AJAX call
                }
            },
            'Cancel' : function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I'm using FF 3.6. I think this was my fault. This had worked for the very first time I triggered the dialog. Turns out I was not removing the dialog's div which contained the input box. So when I popped the dialog again and clicked Save, it was reading the stale value from the input box created for the previous dialog invocation. I don't remember why I wrongly assumed the button is not working anymore. A simple alert statement would've proved it was right. Now I intercept the dialog's close event so as to remove the dialog's div. This way the input box get created fresh everytime. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually the code is working. only thing here is you can't realize it because of miss-configured test scenario ( at least I think so, LoL )

```
var message = "Please provide Phone number."
var phoneNum = "<input type='text' id='phoneNum' name='phoneNum'/> ";
var dialogHtml = "<div id='confirmPhoneNumber'>"  + message + phoneNum + "<div id='dialogError' style='display:none'></div>" + "</div>";
$('body').append(dialogHtml);
$("#confirmPhoneNumber").css("font-size", "70%");
$("#confirmPhoneNumber").dialog({
    resizable : false,
    modal : true,
    title : 'Save Phone',
    buttons : {
        'Save' : function () {
            // Phone number must be provided
            if ($.trim($("#phoneNum").val()).length == 0){
                $("#dialogError").html("error occured, fill the textfield please");
                $("#dialogError").show();
            } else {
                $("#dialogError").html("now it is working " + $("#phoneNum").val());
                $("#dialogError").show();
            // Make AJAX call
            }
        },
        'Cancel' : function () {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    }
});
```

if you test this, you will see that there is no unbinding at all.

**EDİT** : re-configured the if check in save button. hope this will work.

Comment: The problem actually isn't with the button being unbound - it's the fact there is an error in the script for IE. So when it occurs the script stops all together, making it seem like the button is no longer bound. `.trim()` isn't a function in IE.

Comment: yep that's right. I misunderstood. what he need to do is : change the if check to : 

if ($.trim($("#phoneNum").val()).length == 0)

Comment: This looks much better than mine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are you testing with IE? Are you getting any errors on the page?

If you take a look *(I'm testing with chrome)* [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/FyBS8/1/) it works, it will allow you to press the button, it will show the error, enter something, click again and it alerts. So the button is still working.

However, IE doesn't work - it shows an error.....***`.trim()` isn't a supported function by IE***. So you can use [**jQuery's .trim()**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) instead:

```
$("#confirmPhoneNumber").dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    resizable: false,
    modal: true,
    title: 'Save Phone',
    buttons: {
        'Save': function() {
            // Phone number must be provided
            if ( $.trim($("#phoneNum").val()).length == 0) {
                 $("#dialogError").show();
            } else {
                alert('Got a number');
            }
        },
        'Cancel': function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    }
});
```

Try again [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/FyBS8/3/) it works with IE.

*Take a look at [**Trim in javascript not working in IE**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308134/trim-in-javascript-not-working-in-ie).*

Comment: I'm testing in FireFox 3.6 though. Also, I don't want to use alert since it will bring its own popup. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Ignore my comment about alert. I guess you used it just for demo.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle validation process like this

```
           'Save' : function () {
                var valid = true;

                // Phone number must be provided
                if ($("#phoneNum").val().trim().length == 0) {
                    $("#dialogError").show();
                    valid = false;
                }
                //any other validations


                if (valid === true) {
                // Make AJAX call
                }
            },
```

so validation could be called more than once, and if all valid - form'll be processed

Comment: this doesn't remotely answer the question - it's just different logic within the event handler.

Comment: emm.. sorry, but i can't think why one need to rebuild `save` handler after first validation? what if the second try to fill form was unsuccessfull too?

Comment: you _don't_ have to rebuild the button handler, they're not unbound after each press. there must be some other bug.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the 'live' method to bind to the control.  but this is generally used in case new controls are dynamically created.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI **doesn't** unbind the click handler on a dialog button once it's pressed.

See a demo at http://jsfiddle.net/MwNJd/2/

You must have something else going on.