# IE 8 javascript problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Hi following code throws the "Object doesn't support this property or method" error in IE..
    `var value = $input.val().replace(/ /g, '').trim();`
It is part of form validation, in every other browser is it working well, but in IE it doesnt..please help

Comment: `trim()` was introduced with ECMAScript 5 and IE8 does not support this. Actually it does not seem you need `trime` anyway, because you already remove every space by calling `replace(/ /g, '')`. If you are worried about the other whitespace characters, you could use `\s`: `$input.val().replace(/\s+/g, '')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Ben Rowe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308134/trim-in-javascript-not-working-in-ie/2308157#2308157): Add the following code to add trim functionality to the string.

```
if(typeof String.prototype.trim !== 'function') {
  String.prototype.trim = function() {
    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As was commented on your question, IE8 doesn't support `trim()`. jQuery includes the [`trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) function, so I'd use that:

```
var value = jQuery.trim($input.val().replace(/ /g, ''));
```

Comment: Sorry, I can only accept only one answer:)But thanks, I'd read the api and not mindless autowrite the code:DI thought I was using trim form jQuery..Everything clear already