# This code doesn't work in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, cross-browser

Hi so I have this jQuery/JS script. That basically takes an encoded URL string and parses it and saves variable values into variables.

Basically what PHP's $_GET does.

```
function getUrlVars() 
{
 var map = {}; 
 var parts = window.location.search.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)(=[^&]*)?/gi, 

   function(m,key,value) 
     { map[key] = (value === undefined) ? true : value.substring(1); }); 

 return map; 
}
```

Basically this script does what I want. From this URL string:

```
/autopop.html?Email=test%40test.com&LastName=Test+last&&FirstName=+Test+First
```

I get the values:

```
Email = test%40test.com

LastName = Test+last

FirstName = +Test+First
```

What I want to do is Auto-populate a form on this same page with this information.
(I know what you're thinking a server-side script would be a better solution but the boss says we don't have access to that, trust me, I've tried)

Long story short, here's the rest of my code:

```
var keys = getUrlVars();

$(document).ready(function(){
    var fname = keys['FirstName'].replace(/\+/g , " ").trim();
    var lname = keys['LastName'].replace(/\+/g , " ").trim();
    var email = decodeURIComponent(keys['Contact0Email'].replace(/\+/g , " ")).trim();
    $("#Email").val(email);
    $("#FirstName").val(fname);
    $("#LastName").val(lname);
});
```

This code gets the job done. All except for one browser. IE.

IE doesn't support `decodeURIComponent` or so I've read. In any case, I tried using other functions like `decodeURI` and `escape` all producing unwanted results.

My google searches have yielded nothing but, semi-interesting [articles](http://xkr.us/articles/javascript/encode-compare/) (totally off-topic but thought I'd just share that).

No solutions. Can anyone shed some light? How do I make this work on IE?

Comment: What do the unwanted results look like?

Comment: Clean Text? It's not the resulting text that I'm having problems with it's browser compatibility. This works in all other browsers except IE8 and below.IE9 apparently supports it.

Comment: then IE8 should show you an error. What does that error say?

Comment: @pekka I don't remember anymore. I just recently upgraded to IE9. But it said something about a function not being supported. I thought it was decodeURIComponent at first but as @Shadow pointed out below, it's the .trim() function that's causing the crash. I'll need some time to test it but it seems to be the right answer.

Comment: fair enough. In future questions, always remember to add the exact error message - it is usually impossible or very hard to tell what's wrong only from seeing the code.  Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have read wrong, `decodeURIComponent` [works just fine in IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91b80x6x%28v=vs.94%29.aspx), even in IE6.

However, `trim` doesn't work in IE browsers [prior to IE 9](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff679971%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) and that's what causing your script to crash.

For working alternative, see the accepted answer here: [.trim() in JavaScript not working in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308134/trim-in-javascript-not-working-in-ie)
Or use the jQuery `trim()` method as you're already using jQuery anyway.