# Remove '&nbsp;'

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, whitespace, html-entities

I'm looking for a way to delete `'&nbsp;'` from my html code, found number of ways on stackoverflow.com, but neither of those seam to work!

**HTML**

```
<p>No Space</p>
<p>&nbsp;1 Space</p>
<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;2 Spaces</p>
<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;3 Spaces</p>
<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;4 Spaces</p>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('p').text().replace(/ /g, '');
    //$('p').html($(this).html().replace(/&nbsp;/gi,''));

});
```

**jsfiddle - playground**  http://jsfiddle.net/MrTest/hbvjQ/85/

Comment: Maybe you mean `&nbsp;` not `&nbsp`.

Comment: @Karlois , @DanielB - sorry, corrected now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.trim() in JavaScript not working in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308134/trim-in-javascript-not-working-in-ie)

Comment: @DanielB - **your** HTML is invalid. It should be `&nbsp;` (you have `$` instead of `&`) :)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You have &nbsp in your code instead of `&nbsp;`

```
$('p').each(function(){
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/&nbsp;/gi,''));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/genesis/hbvjQ/76/

Answer (score 32):

This one will replace every white-space character:

```
$('p').text(function (i, old) {
    return old.replace(/\s/g, '')
});
```

Or if you only want to replace non-breaking spaces:

```
$('p').text(function (i, old) {
    return old.replace(/\u00A0/g, '')
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hbvjQ/79/)

I am setting the new value using a [closure as a parameter for `.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text2).

---

Please note that HTML entities need a closing `;` in the end.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a non-jQuery answer, since using jQuery for such a task is overkill unless you're already using it for something else on your site:

```js
var p = document.getElementsByTagName('p');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(p, function(el) {
  el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(/&nbsp;/gi, '');
});
```

```html
<p>No Space</p>
<p>&nbsp;1 Space</p>
<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;2 Spaces</p>
<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;3 Spaces</p>
<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;4 Spaces</p>
```

Answer (score 6):

try

```
$('p').each(function() {
     $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/ /g, ''));
});
```

or if you wish to delete the &nbsp try

```
$('p').each(function() {
      $(this).html($(this).html().replace('&nbsp;', ''));
});
```

also please note that space is `&nbsp;` and not &nbsp (you are missing ;)

Answer (score 5):

Based on [bažmegakapa' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6452785/288906), this can be used on elements containing other elements.

```
$('p').html(function (i, old) {
    return old.replace(/&nbsp;/g, '')
});
```

`.text()` gets rid of html elements; `.html()` does not

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code:

```
$('p').each( function() {
    var elem = $( this );
    elem.html( elem.html().replace( /&nbsp;/g,'' ) );
} );
```

And here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hbvjQ/62/