# Add hanging indent to text inside of <li>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, text-indent

(edited several times for clarity)

**Note: I am not the one writing the HTML.**

Here is the format of the HTML (note: the links and text after the links are on the same line):

```
<li>
    <strong>Title of section</strong>
    <br>

    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <!-- Add hanging indent to subsequent lines if text goes onto second line-->
    <a>link here</a> Some text here...
    <br>

    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <!-- Add hanging indent to subsequent lines if text goes onto second line-->
    <a>another link</a> More Text ... 
</li>
```

What I am trying to do is add a hanging indent to the each line that begins with the link and continues with text so that if the text continues to the next line, the subsequent lines will be indented.

[Example of hanging indent](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/H/hanging_indent.html) (thank you @Mohsen)

Illustration of problem (the line beginning with yellow text starts too far to the left, it should be indented so that it lines up with "link" on the line above it"):
[image]

Is there a way to do this with pure CSS? If not, with javascript or jQuery?

Comment: hanging indent meaning ?

Comment: 'I am not the one writing the HTML' 

Great...

Comment: [hanging indent](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/H/hanging_indent.html)

Comment: Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/gFeNp/) what you are after??

Answer (score 5):

This can be achieved using `text-indent` and `padding-left`/`margin-left`.

```
li{
    text-indent: -25px;
    padding-left: 25px;
}
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tPJvZ/)

There is also a value `hanging` for "*text-indent*" property (experimental). check [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-indent).

Comment: Rather than keeping the `&nbsp;`s, I think it'd be best to remove them and just increase the magnitude of the `text-indent` and `padding-left`. This is, however, assuming the HTML can be edited.

Comment: @Mr_Green: This isn't what I'm looking for. The lines that start with links are in the right place. It is only if those lines wrap that the problem occurs.

Comment: @dmr try using `ul,li{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}` in css code.

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS:

```
li{
    list-style:none;
    padding-left:10px;
}
li strong{
    display:block;
    margin-left:-10px
}
```

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/N8QXX/)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the text in a `<span>` and then style that with left margin/padding.

EDIT: 
Add a margin-right to the anchors if you can't edit the HTML

Comment: Note: I am not the one writing the HTML.

Comment: Could have been a comment my fair friend.

Comment: @user1671639 we can still hope he is the one who wrote the CSS/JS  ;)

Answer (score 0):

I take it the link and the text are supposed to be on the same line. If so, try using CSS

`li a{
display: inline-block;
margin-right: 2em;
}`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a script free solution to your problem, as the white spaces seem to make it impossible. How about this: Indent everything in the `<li>`-element, bring back the title and remove all whitespaces.

**CSS**

```
li {
    padding-left: 10px;
}

li > strong {
    display:block;
    margin: 0 0 0 -10px;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('ul > li').each(function() {
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/&nbsp;/gi, ''));
});
```

The replacement function is adapted from [genesis'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/764846/genesis) answer to "[Remove '`&nbsp;`' - still trying](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6452789/1456376)".

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/P6zhb/)

Answer (score 0):

Do not use non-breaking whitespaces for indentation. They would only indent the first line, as you are experiencing. Instead, use the proper HTML:

```
<li>
    <strong>Title of section</strong>
    <p><a>link here</a> Some text here that might go into a second line</p>
    <p><a>another link</a> More Text that is indented even in subsequent lines when text goes onto second or more lines</p>
</li>
```

Now you can indent the paragraphs with `margin-left` or `padding-left`, and if you want to indent the first line differently (in either direction) you can use `text-indent`.

Comment: I don't have control over the HTML. I can only change it with javascript/jQuery or use a CSS only solution.