# Formatting a french number

Tags: javascript

I have a french number: 1 138. The string is `1&nbsp;138`

I want to replace all the `&nbsp;` with `''`.

I do

```
alert(document.getElementById('gvdesglose_programas_ctl03_lblndescargas').innerHTML.replaceAll(/\&nbsp\;|\s/g,''))
```

But it doesn't change. I don't know why.

Comment: Could it be that your regex search is specifically looking for `&nbsp;` and the character within the search string is simply a `' '` whitespace character? See [this answer for more insight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357078/whats-the-difference-between-nbsp-and)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove '&nbsp;' - still trying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452731/remove-nbsp-still-trying)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript regex replace html chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229518/javascript-regex-replace-html-chars)

Comment: You try to replace literal chars sequence `&nbsp;` and not HTML entity `&nbsp;`, that is actually one character

Comment: BTW, there's not point using `replaceAll` if your doing `/g` regex. just saying.

Comment: `innerHTML` will return the replaced HTML entity not the original source - try `innerText` instead.