# IE9 ignores angular objects (within ngRepeat)

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-9, angularjs

I've got an `ng-include` and `ng-controller` within an `ng-repeat`, and IE randomly craps itself when it sees the child instance object of the repeat:

inside main.html

```
<section ng-repeat="panel in sidepanels">
  <h2 class="twelve columns">
    <span class="twelve">
      <i class="icon {{panel.icon}}"></i> <!-- resolves properly -->
      {{panel.controller.name}} <!-- empty -->
    </span>
  </h2>
  <div
    ng-include src="'views/'+panel.controller.name.toLowerCase()+'.html'"
    ng-controller="panel.controller"
  ></div>
</section>
```

inside controllers.js

```
function Main($scope) {
  …
  $scope.sidepanels = [
    {
      "controller": Alerts,
      "icon": "icon-warning-sign"
    }
  ];
  …
}

function Alerts($scope,WebSocket) {
  $scope.alerts = [];
  WebSocket.on('…', function(data) { … });
  WebSocket… //WebSocket is a Service
}
```

Except instead of throwing an error in console, it just silently ignores the fact that it sometimes can't resolve `panel`. I only noticed this was the case because I saw a failed GET on `views/.html`.

I checked [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms534187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and supposedly IE supports the `name` property.

Comment: Is `Alerts` an object? Can you provide its content (or an example)?

Comment: Yes, Alert is an object (controller function). I provides methods for handling websocket messages.

Comment: @bmleite sorry forgot to tag you before

Comment: As I can see your `Alerts` functions gets information from server. I realized that your code is correct. However when the template is being initialized you might have value of `panel.controller.name.toLowerCase()` as uninitialized or empty.

Comment: Something is definitely causing it to be empty or ignored. I don't think `Alerts` is uninitialised when the template is processed because `controllers.js` is included from my doc's head, so it should have already been processed long before angular includes template files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property `name` doesn't work very well for functions on IE.

You can use the following snippet to retrieve a function's name (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6903860/651480)):

```
func.toString().match(/^function ([^(\s]+)/)[1]
```

Add a function to your `Main` controller that creates the template path, like this:

```
$scope.getTemplatePath= function(controller) {
    return 'views/' + angular.lowercase(controller.toString().match(/^function ([^(\s]+)/)[1] + '.html');    
};
```

And on the HTML:

```
<div ng-include="getTemplatePath(panel.controller)" ng-controller="panel.controller"></div>
```

**jsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/bmleite/faGRk/

Comment: sweet thanks! I'll check this out when I have access to IE on Monday.