# Print function names of an array of functions

Tags: javascript

Say I have the array [func1, func2, func3].

I would like to print out as a string: "func1, func2, func3". However, it prints the entire contents of the function.

Would I have to do some regex to grab the name from the output or is there an easier method?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Function `name` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name):

```
function doSomething() { }

alert(doSomething.name); // alerts "doSomething"
```

Be aware, that according to the documentation, this does not work in Internet Explorer.  You can look into [other options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6903762/function-name-not-supported-in-ie) if that is important for you.

Answer (score 0):

You want to get the function names in a list, right?
If that is the case, something like this should work for you.Please let me know if this is not what you wanted to do. 
[JsFiddle Working code here](http://jsfiddle.net/dJRUG/1/)

```
//declare the dummy functions
function funcOne(){
    return null;
}
function funcTwo(){
    return null;
}
function funcThree(){
    return null;
}
//add the functions to the array
var functionArray=[funcOne,funcTwo,funcThree];
//declare an output array so we can then join the names easily
var output=new Array();
//iterate the array using the for .. in loop and then just getting the function.name property
for(var funcName in functionArray){
    if(functionArray.hasOwnProperty(funcName))
        output.push(functionArray[funcName].name);
}
//join the output and show it
alert(output.join(","));
```