# Angular2 - No provider for ExceptionHandler

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, angular, angular2-services

I am trying to integrate angular2 in my PHP app.
Here are the steps I have performed

1. Included necessary JS:

`../node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js
../node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js
../node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js
../node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js
../node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js`

2. Created angular2 component in Typescript:

`import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'hello-world',
    template: 'My First Angular 2 App'
})

export class AppComponent { }`

3. Config:

`<script>
  System.config({
    transpiler: 'typescript',
    typescriptOptions: { emitDecoratorMetadata: true }
});
</script>`

4. Bootstrap:

`<script>
  System.import('angular2/platform/browser').then(function(ng){
    System.import('js/app.ts').then(function(src) {
      ng.bootstrap(src.AppComponent);
    }).then(null, console.error.bind(console));
   });
</script>`

Output:
[image]

**EDIT:**

It seems that there is a conflict with prototype.js and angular 2. See the pluker: http://plnkr.co/edit/XKKpriTPrTX3tXqqz8v2?p=preview

Answer (score 3):

I got this error a couple of times. According to this: [Angular Quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html)

You might be missing a couple of scripts:

```
<script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>
```

If using Internet Explorer, you should also remember to include:

```
<script src="node_modules/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js"></script>
```

Comment: is there seprate shim file for every browser like IE ?

Comment: @PardeepJain Not that i'm aware, but you can probably go over the files in that folder to see what's there :)

Comment: @PardeepJain: No there is not. The reason to have this for IE11 can be found from that files contents. For example the `function.name` does work on all other major browsers but not in IE. [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6903762) more details.

Comment: @RoopeHakulinen I actually think this is meant for >IE8, not just IE11.