# Object doesn't support property or method 'keys' - (IE11)

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-11

I can't figure out what is the problem in ***IE11***.
App works well ***without any issue*** in other browsers like chrome, firefox etc.

[image]

Comment: What does `document.documentMode` return? Should be 11.

Comment: What is that and how to check?

Comment: Probably some of https://github.com/angular/angular/search?q=IE11&state=open&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93

Comment: did you include the es6-shim?

Comment: @pixelBits - nope.  please guide what to do?

Comment: include es6 shim and polyfills:     <script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script><script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script><script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>

Comment: In which file should I include these scripts? in index.html?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to include `es6-shim` because IE 11 doesn't support [`Map.prototype.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/keys)

https://github.com/paulmillr/es6-shim

Or you can import directly from cdn:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es5-shim/4.4.1/es5-shim.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-shim/0.34.1/es6-shim.js"></script>
```

Check this related issues:

- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6479
- https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed/issues/145

Comment: This solution fixed this error. But raised new error `The use of a keyword for an identifier is invalid` which still seems open issue @ https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6501

Comment: in the linked issue, there is a suggested script as a work-around: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js

Answer (score 1):

"The use of a keyword for an identifier in invalid" on IE 11 is still an issue for Angular2 beta 6:

http://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6501

In the thread, there is a work-around that [seems to work](http://plnkr.co/edit/QKU0RNI98k7c7Z0y5sSM?p=preview):

```
// function.name (all IE)
/*! @source http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6903762/function-name-not-supported-in-ie*/
if (!Object.hasOwnProperty('name')) {
  Object.defineProperty(Function.prototype, 'name', {
    get: function() {
      var matches = this.toString().match(/^\s*function\s*(\S[^\(]*)\s*\(/);
      var name = matches && matches.length > 1 ? matches[1] : "";
      // For better performance only parse once, and then cache the
      // result through a new accessor for repeated access.
      Object.defineProperty(this, 'name', {value: name});
      return name;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Where to write this?

Comment: did you check out the plnkr link?

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same error when using webpack and 2.0.0.rc1.

If anyone have the same problem, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41042539/2161698) is how I made it work.

Basically I included on index.html the scripts

```
es6-shim.min.js
system-polyfills.js
shims_for_IE.js
```

when the browser is IE or Safari.