# Necessary imports for ES6 to run Angular 4 application on IE11

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6, internet-explorer-11

I'm creating an application using Angular4, I'd like to correspond to IE11.
polyfills.ts is designated like ex), but is other designation necessary?

ex)

```
import "core-js/es6/symbol";
import "core-js/es6/object";
import "core-js/es6/function";
import "core-js/es6/parse-int";
import "core-js/es6/parse-float";
import "core-js/es6/number";
import "core-js/es6/math";
import "core-js/es6/string";
import "core-js/es6/date";
import "core-js/es6/array";
import "core-js/es6/regexp";
import "core-js/es6/map";
import "core-js/es6/set";
import "core-js/es6/reflect";

import "core-js/es7/reflect";
import "zone.js/dist/zone";
```

I referred to Browser Support (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/browser-support.html),
but I do not know what is necessary to import out of ES6 because it is written only with ES6.

Comment: You can refer to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40490987/angular-2-webpack-site-wont-work-on-server-in-ie-11. Important ones would be the shim library

Comment: @Thiagz I import core-js/es6 with polyfills.ts, but do I need additional shim library for this?

Comment: I included only these 3.. babel-polyfill, zone.js, and reflect-metada. After that my code was working fine on IE[11,10,9,8]

Comment: @Thiagz babel-polyfill, zone.js, and reflect-metada don't exist in URL you showed, but is there a site to which you referred to use these?

Comment: You can find those libraries in https://www.npmjs.com/ . Just import it to your project and your app will work fine

Answer (score 0):

Why don't u use the Angular CLI to set up your project? This way everything is set up correctly and after that you're free to do what ever you want.

- [Angular CLI](https://cli.angular.io)
- [Browser support](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/browser-support.html)

Comment: When using Angular CLI, a no problem thing was understood in generated polyfills.ts. es6-shim.min.js and shims_for_IE.js are a module equal to core-js/es6, Is the recognition that core-js/es6 being used as the formula of Angular right?