# upgrading from rc4 to rc5: setting up dependencies

Tags: angular

I reviewed the relevant answers in this regard, and found them extremely helpful in figuring out the setup for bootstrapping rc5 apps. however, i am still receiving an error, after setting up my files as follows:

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
//import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { routes } from './app.routes';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Calendar, DataTable, Column, InputMask } from 'primeng/primeng';

import { FooModule }  from './+foo/foo.module';
import { BarModule }  from './+bar/bar.module';
import { BooModule }  from './+boo/boo.module';
@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule,
            HttpModule,
            RouterModule,
            FooModule,
            BarModule,
            BooModule
  ], 
  declarations: [AppComponent,Calendar, DataTable, Column, ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
      useValue: '<%= APP_BASE %>',
    }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]

})

export class AppModule { }
```

My components and modules look like this:

```
import { NgModule }                     from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule, NgControl }                  from '@angular/common';
//import { FormsModule }                    from '@angular/forms';

import { SomeDirective } from '../../SomeDirective.directive';
import { SomePipe } from '../../SomePipe.pipe';
import { SomeService } from './SomeService.service';

import { ContextMenu, Menu } from 'primeng/primeng';

@NgModule({
  imports: [//modules

    ],
  declarations: [//Directives, components and pipes
      SomeDirective, SomePipe
  ],
  providers: [//services
      NgControl, SomeService
  ]  
})

export class FooModule {}
```

and

```
import {RouterModule, Router} from '@angular/router'
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FORM_DIRECTIVES, NgControl } from '@angular/common';
import { MenuItem} from 'primeng/primeng';
import { SomeService } from './SomeService.service';
import { someInterface } from './someInterfaces';


@Component({ 
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: '...', 
  templateUrl: '....html',
  styleUrls: ['....component.css'],
})


export class PatientSearchComponent implements OnInit {
   stateService: SomeService;
   obj: any[] = [];   

  constructor(private aService: SomeService, private router: Router,   aService: SomeService) { 
...  }

  someFunction() {
     ...
     });
 }
```

i followed some answers on git, specifically https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10805 and https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10617. i placed my dependencies in the declarations, imports, etc. based on #brandonroberts's comments.

(one part i wasn't sure about, and perhaps this is where the problem is (though both ways i went, i got an error....), was where shared components go. in the imports? of each module which uses them, or of app.module? or does it go in the declarations of app.module??)

i am getting the following error :(,

```
localhost/:142 Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of null(…)
```

it seems like a problem with app.module.ts, but what is it?

Thanks!

EDIT
index.html

```
<body>

  <sd-app>Loading...</sd-app>

  <script>
  // function.name (all IE)
  // Remove once https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6501 is fixed.
  /*! @source http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6903762/function-name-not-supported-in-ie*/
  if (!Object.hasOwnProperty('name')) {
    Object.defineProperty(Function.prototype, 'name', {
      get: function() {
        var matches = this.toString().match(/^\s*function\s*((?![0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9_$]*)\s*\(/);
        var name = matches && matches.length > 1 ? matches[1] : "";
        // For better performance only parse once, and then cache the
        // result through a new accessor for repeated access.
        Object.defineProperty(this, 'name', {value: name});
        return name;
      }
    });
  }
  </script>

  <script>
  // Fixes undefined module function in SystemJS bundle
  function module() {}
  </script>

  <!-- shims:js -->
  <!-- endinject -->

  <% if (ENV === 'dev') { %>
  <script>
    System.config(<%=
      JSON.stringify(SYSTEM_CONFIG, null, 2)
    %>)
  </script>
  <% } %>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->

  <!--<script src="node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/bundles/ng2-bootstrap.min.js"></script>-->

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- libs:js -->
  <!-- endinject -->

  <!-- inject:js -->
  <!-- endinject -->

  <% if (ENV === 'dev') { %>
  <script>
  System.import('<%= BOOTSTRAP_MODULE %>')
    .catch(function (e) {
      console.error(e,
        'Report this error');
    });
  </script>
  <% } %>
</body>
```

adding the following files:
main.ts

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

and +Foo/index.ts

```
export * from './foo.component';
export * from './foo.routes';
```

Comment: Why did you add `NgControl` to providers. I think importing `FormsModule` and `ReactiveFormsModule` should do.

Comment: I assume `foo,
            bar,
            boo` are all modules?

Comment: Importing `RouterModule` should be enough and `ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,` in declarations should not be needed. AFAIK `declarations: []` should only contain components and directives from the current module.

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer, obviously only from the current module for the children module. but how about app.module? does it hold the shared items? like if i am referring to the same module from more then one module, how should i reference it? referencing it separately throughs an error.

Comment: Sounds like https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10671 also this comment https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10671#issuecomment-241156513 might help.

Comment: If the error appears in localhost/:, that probably means it is somewhere in your index.html (or whatever file you use to bootstrap your web application). Could you include that to your question, too ?

Comment: basically, rebuild all dependancies from scratch? i can't see how it will work before all dependencies are in place though

Comment: thanks guys, added index.html

Comment: error now appears in index (previously did appear under localhost, must have changed with last updates?)
(index):142 Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of null(…) "Report this error"

Comment: Can you tell, using your browser's debug tools, which line corresponds to line 142 of the main page ? It's hard to tell because it looks like you use a preprocessor on your HTML file. Maybe include your index page as the browser sees it, at least around this line 142 ?

Comment: `<script>
  System.import('app/main')
    .catch(function (e) {
      console.error(e,
        'Report this error');
    });
  </script>`

Comment: thanks everyone, i removed my dependencies and added them back in one by one. turned out that i placed modules in the imports section of one of the modules.

Answer (score 0):

What caused the error was the fact that i was importing modules via the imports section, instead of the declarations. had to remove all dependancies and add them one by one in order to track which item was causing the errors.