# Catch Bound Event In IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

Get Object function name from event list on IE works fine in Chrome btw

Example

```
var foo = {
 fookeydown:function(e){
   e.which;
   ... do something
 }
}
$(document).on("keydown",foo.fookeydown)
$._data(document,"events").keydown[0].handler.name // return me fookeydown in Chrome 
 but ie is nut
```

Comment: Does my question makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access a function's property [`function.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name), which is not defined for IE. You could try the following [implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17056530/4051471) to define it (Notice the function name given to the function in `foo`):

```js
if (!(function f() {}).name) {
  Object.defineProperty(Function.prototype, 'name', {
    get: function() {
      var name = (this.toString().match(/^function\s*([^\s(]+)/) || [])[1];
      Object.defineProperty(this, 'name', {
        value: name
      });
      return name;
    }
  });
}

var foo = {
  fookeydown: function fookeydown(e) {
    console.log(e.which, 'keydown');
    console.log($._data(document, "events").keydown[0].handler.name);
  }
};
$(document).on("keydown", foo.fookeydown);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Alternative, searching in `foo.fooProp`:

```js
var foo = {
  fooProp: {
    foofookeydown: function(e) {
      console.log(e.which, 'keydown');
      console.log($._data(document, "events").keydown[0].handler.name);
    },
    init: function() {
      $(document).on("keydown", this.foofookeydown);
    },
  },
  init: function() {
    this.fooProp.init()
  }
};

if (!(function f() {}).name) {
  Object.defineProperty(Function.prototype, 'name', {
    get: function() {
      var name = '';
      var values = Object.keys(foo.fooProp).map(function(e) {
        return foo.fooProp[e]
      });
      if (values.length > 0) {
        if (values.indexOf(this) > -1)
          name = Object.keys(foo.fooProp)[values.indexOf(this)];
      }
      Object.defineProperty(this, 'name', {
        value: name
      });
      return name;
    }
  });
}

foo.init();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi it working in this demo but i cant figure it out how to implement on my code which is structure like this just copy paste top of section ?

Comment: precisely, whenever you're initiating the dom you can put that code

Comment: @MunkhdelgerTumenbayar you can refer the edited answer where you execute IE related code

Comment: Not quite sure about it but i ended up getting `name : undefined' i put top of my code , on ready not quit working

Comment: holy dick i didn't notice you put fookeydown as function name

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention regex `.match(/^function\s*([^\s(]+)/) || [])[1]` only when the function has a name and is not anonymous

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199404/discussion-between-shrys-and-munkhdelger-tumenbayar).