# Javascript line breaking in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-events

I have a script which is using this line as part of some geocoding.

```
var dms = String(dmsStr).trim().replace(/^-/,'').replace(/[NSEW]$/i,'').split(/[^0-9.,]+/);
```

It works fine in all browsers apart from IE, which is kicking out an error.

I'm sending it parameters.

> 0.5501039994056782

It's not my code I'm just debugging it. I'm assuming it could be a problem with Typecasting it to a string, given that it's clearly a number.

But I'd love some feedback.

Comment: *"which is kicking out an error..."* ***What*** error?!

Comment: Comments below worked a treat.

Comment: Check this for further info though. Great answer worked a treat. Got stuck further down the line now. If anybody feels like being extra help, check this url for help diagnosing the next problem. client.bytewire.co.uk/marblesolar/roof-calculator What you should see happen is a directional line being drawn on the google map. See other browsers for test. IE reports a failure in jQuery and then due to that fails to pass correct data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `String.trim()` in IE8. You can add it like this:

```
if(typeof String.prototype.trim !== 'function') {
  String.prototype.trim = function() {
    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''); 
  }
}
```

as per [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308134/trim-in-javascript-not-working-in-ie/2308157#2308157)

Comment: Great answer worked a treat. Got stuck further down the line now. If anybody feels like being extra help, check this url for help diagnosing the next problem. http://client.bytewire.co.uk/marblesolar/roof-calculator/ What you should see happen is a directional line being drawn on the google map. See other browsers for test. IE reports a failure in jQuery and then due to that fails to pass correct data.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think IE has `trim()`. Try this:

```
if(typeof String.prototype.trim !== 'function') {
  String.prototype.trim = function() {
    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''); 
  }
}
```

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308134/trim-in-javascript-not-working-in-ie) for more information

Answer (score 0):

the exact error is

```
"Object doesn't support property or method 'trim'"
```

so to solve you could do:

```
var dms = jQuery.trim(String(dmsStr)).replace(/^-/,'').replace(/[NSEW]$/i,'').split(/[^0-9.,]+/);
```