# Jquery issues on older versions of IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I have the following statement in document.ready function:

```
  if($("sidebar ").html().trim().length == 0)
  {
    $("sidebar").append("<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;The sides..</p>"); 
  };
```

It works fine in IE 9 but as soon as I select IE 8 (browser and document standard), the script stops working and gives the following error:

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'trim': object is null or undefined 
application-e51c9eee7d22e9644481115dc1fedd5f.js, line 7 character 17578
```

I looked at the .js in debug mode and see that my statement above is transformed to:

```
$("sidebar ").html().trim().length==0&&$("sidebar").append("<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;The sides..</p>")
```

How do I prevent this error?  Please note that I do see that the  node is present in the rendered page.

I thought that maybe just having reference to shiv5.html may not be sufficient to take care of the IE idiosyncrasies. So, I have added modernizr.js via sprockets and I have added class="no-js" in my layout.  Still no luck in IE <9.

What am I missing?  What else can I do to get the favor of Microsoft overlords?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to MDN, [`trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) isn't available in IE < 9.

You could use [`$.trim`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.trim) instead:

```
if($.trim($("sidebar ").html()).length == 0)
{
  $("sidebar").append("<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;The sides..</p>"); 
} // <-- Don't want a semicolon here.
```

The MDN article lists an alternative if you don't want to find all the instances of `trim` and correct them. You could use the following to create `.trim` if it's not natively available:

```
if(!String.prototype.trim) {
  String.prototype.trim = function () {
    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew!  That solved the issue with trim.  But IE 8 still complains about the overall snippet of code.  Now it is complaining about an "unexpected call" when it hits "append". Any suggestions? Here is the actual error:  SCRIPT65535: Unexpected call to method or property access. 
application-49b3f7c89f7bb90bcdd86761195a59d1.js, line 6 character 15114

Comment: Andrew - yes, the same piece of code.  But I think I figured out the issue.  Apparently it was because my node was called sidebar.  I just changed it to a <div> with class and id of sidebar, made appropriate changes to the css and js, and bam it worked!  Thanks for providing the trim solution. That was a tough nut to crack!

Answer (score 0):

[Check out this thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308134/trim-in-javascript-not-working-in-ie) After a quick search it seems that many people are experiencing issues with trim.