# JavaScript String Comparison in IE8

Tags: javascript, string, internet-explorer, comparison, string-comparison

I'm trying to compare two strings and for some reason, I'm getting "false" as the result.

I've broken down the code to it's most simple function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function selectCat(cat) {
    var catName = cat.firstChild.nodeValue;
    alert(catName);
    if(catName.toString() == "Acronyms") {
        alert("True");
    } else {
        alert("False");
    }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<ul>
<li onclick="selectCat(this)">Acronyms</li>
</ul>
</body>
```

This works just fine in Dreamweaver's Live View, as well as in IE8 (when I press F12 to preview). However, when I upload this page to my company's web content manager (IBM WebSphere Portal), it no longer works.

I don't know what is different between the environments, but it's pretty frustrating. Anyone have any ideas why it might not be treating the category name as a String?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason IE is including an extra space at the end of the nodeValue ie what you are actually getting is "Acronyms ".

**Edit**:
To remove the trailing space you can add

```
if(catName.charAt(catName.length-1) == " "){
    catName = catName.substr(0,catName.length-1);
}
```

Comment: This worked PERFECTLY, thank you sooo much Ryan! I had no idea that IE could do this/did this.

Answer (score 1):

If IE is including an extra space at the end of nodeValue try -

```
var catName; 
catName = (catName.toString()).trim();
```

and then compare it with "Acronyms".

Comment: I didn't know that it might do that, I'll give it a try!

Comment: Tried it and for some reason, I get the following message in IE8...

`Message: Object doesn't support this property or method`

Comment: Check this out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308134/trim-in-javascript-not-working-in-ie