# Extract number from whitespaces

Tags: javascript, regex

Value is something like this: `12 23 345 3454 21`.

I require to get numbers out of this and store into the Array so my array should look like 
`values = new Array(12,23,345,3454,21);`.

My problem is I can remove white spaces but it comes as `1223345345421`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `split(" ")` to split the string along white spaces.

To be more thorough, you should trim the leading and trailing spaces, and split along multiple space characters:

```
> var numbers_in_string = "   12   23 345 3454    21    ";
> var numbers_in_array = numbers_in_string.trim().split(/\s+/);
> console.log(numbers_in_arrays)
["12", "23", "345", "3454", "21"]
```

**EDIT**

As @Sangdol has mentioned, trim() may not work in IE9, so you can use include [one of these solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308134/trim-in-javascript-not-working-in-ie) to add trim() functionality to IE9. Or just replace `trim()` with `replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '')`. Either solutions will work as a work-around for cross-browser compatibility.

```
.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '').split(/\s+/)
```

Comment: To save having to convert the elements to numbers later, you can add the following to the end of the solution: .map(function(val){return parseInt(val, 10);})

Answer (score 2):

If it's same pattern, you can use `split()`:

```
var arr = '12 23 345 3454 21'.split(' ');
console.log(arr); // [12, 23, 345, 3454, 21]
```

**Docs:**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to split, you can use match:

```
' 12 23   345   3454   21 '.match(/\d+/g); //12,23,345,3454,21
```

Note that this is more specific to the pattern you are trying to extract, which may suit, or not. You only get the matched patterns so any intervening non-matches (including whitespace) are not returned.