# trim() function doesn't work in IE8?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

Whenever I use the `trim()` function on a string, it works fine with Chrome and Firefox but I get an error in IE8 saying :

> Object doesn't support this property or method

Can anyone tell me why this happens and if there is a work around?

Comment: It's simple, IE8 doesn't support it: http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308134/trim-in-javascript-not-working-in-ie

Comment: this link is helpful for this bug.

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308134/trim-in-javascript-not-working-in-ie][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308134/trim-in-javascript-not-working-in-ie

Answer (score 85, accepted):

IE8 doesn't support the trim function.
Here's a polyfill:

```
if(typeof String.prototype.trim !== 'function') {
  String.prototype.trim = function() {
    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''); 
  };
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what this code snippet is doing?, mainly, what this if statement is about.

Comment: This snippet first checks if the trim function is defined (typeof String.prototype.trim !== 'function')
If it is not defined, it defines the function which is a simple replace with a regular expression

Answer (score 39):

if you want you can add jquery and use $.trim(....) this will work..

```
$.trim("  hello ");
```

give you

```
"hello"
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer - much preferred for sites that are already using jQuery.

Comment: No offense, but I think this should be done only when we are already using javascript. Other wise adding jquery to the site only for one function does not look good. The above solution looks more elegant.

Answer (score 3):

Internet Explorer only started support for `trim()` from version 9.

For reference, the [MDN Polyfill for `String.prototype.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim#Polyfill) is:

```
if (!String.prototype.trim) {
  (function() {
    // Make sure we trim BOM and NBSP
    var rtrim = /^[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+|[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+$/g;
    String.prototype.trim = function() {
      return this.replace(rtrim, '');
    };
  })();
}
```

and the [support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim#Browser_compatibility) for it is:

```
+--------+---------+----+-------+--------+
| Chrome | Firefox | IE | Opera | Safari |
+--------+---------+----+-------+--------+
| All    | 3.5     |  9 | 10.5  |      5 |
+--------+---------+----+-------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Since, I was using jQuery, with the help of @nemo and @karesh-a I came up with:

```
if(typeof String.prototype.trim !== 'function') {
     String.prototype.trim = function(){
        return jQuery.trim( this );
    }
}
```