# Is there a tool to quickly run a short javascript in IE8, without having to run Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

For example, I found that calling something like this

```
document.getElementByID('myElement').value.trim();
```

crash in IE8 because strings don't have trim() in IE8. Is there any way (e.g. using some website in the internet) to run such short, one-off code to verify issues like this without having to find a computer with Internet Explorer?

Comment: Saucelabs.com my friend.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Browserling](https://www.browserling.com/) all the time to make sure html renders properly. I know it does run javascript, but that's in the cloud. The paid version has a feature called "bug hunter" but I don't know exactly what it does. They have a 30 day money-back guarantee so it might be worth trying it for a month. Or you could email them and ask.

Comment: A couple of other links of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11219731/trim-function-doesnt-work-in-ie8 and http://caniuse.com/

Answer (score -1):

Use the Developer tools in the newer versions of IE.
Open IE (desktop mode) and press F12.
In the toolbar, you can select the Browser Mode and the Document Mode.