# Trying to validate form

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

Trying to learn JavaScript, makin decent progress I guess, but I'm stuck at validating a form, tried to see if anybody has the same problem, search didn't turn anything up. So would you please help me?

```
    var minlength = 6;
var pwlength = document.getElementById('psswrd');
var invalid = " ";

function validate() {

    if (pwlength.length < minlength && pwlength == invalid) {
        alert("Password not valid");

    else { 
        alert("Password okay!");
    }
}

submitbtn.onClick = validate();
```

Comment: it should be `var pwlength = document.getElementById('psswrd').value;`

Comment: better `var pwlength = document.getElementById('psswrd').value.length`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- It is not obvious where you call this - I have wrapped it in a window.onload
- you do not access the button correctly. Either of 
  `document.forms[0].submitbtn`
  `document.getElementById("submitbtn")` or 
  `document.getElementsByName("submitbtn")[0]` will work depending on how you name or ID the button HOWEVER do not assign onclick handlers to submit buttons, instead assign submit handler to the form
- there is no point of testing for a single space since that is less than 6 chars anyway.
- && is AND, you mean || OR
- onclick must be all lowercase.
- You assign the onclick to the result of validate instead of validate
- You do not stop the submission

I have taken the trim from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2308157/295783)
and I assume the form has ID="form1"

```
window.onload=function()
  document.getElementById("form1").onsubmit = validate;
}

if(typeof String.prototype.trim !== 'function') { // let's help older IEs
  String.prototype.trim = function() {
    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''); 
  }
}

function validate() {
  var minlength = 6;
  var pw = document.getElementById('psswrd');
  if (pw.value.length < minlength || pw.value.trim() == "") {
    alert("Password not valid");
    pw.focus();
    return false;
  }
  return true; // allow submission  
}
```

Comment: Your variable `pwlength` should always be `0`. Instead, the declaration of `pwval` should be before `pwlength` and the value of `pwlength` should equal `pwval.length`. Of course, with such little lifetimes, do you actually see a need to define variables to such things?

Comment: Great - took a while to find all the problems too. Good luck with your JS studies

Answer (score 0):

```
var minlength = 6;

var pwlength = document.getElementById('psswrd');

var invalid = " ";

function validate() {

    if (pwlength.length < minlength && pwlength == invalid) {
        alert("Password not valid");
}

    else { 
        alert("Password okay!");
    }
}
```

Comment: This code will not work - you are not accessing the value of the field

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems here.

1) **`pwlength.length`** won't get you very far. `pwlength` is equal to an html object, not the value of an html object. Change the actual variable to the following and you should get the correct results:

```
var pwlength = document.getElementById('psswrd').value;
```

2) Before the `else` part of your `if ... else` statement, you need to end the `if` statement by closing it with a curly bracket (`}`). Change that part to the following:

```
} else {
```

3) Your validation to check and see if the length `== invalid` is odd. Double check that and get rid of it.

4) Your onclick event needs to look something like this:

```
submitbtn.onclick = function(){ validate() };
```

**Notice: lowercase event keyword and `function() { ... };` wrapped around the function you want to run.**

Comment: Actually looking at the var name, I would suggest `var pwlength = document.getElementById('psswrd').value.length`