# Identifying an empty text node with jQuery + Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

You'd think this was easy - but I'm having the hardest time with it.

Here's what I'm trying to identify:

```
<span class="cw-value-one"></span>
```

Here's what I'm using so far:

```
    $('span.cw-value-one').each(function(){
        var textNode = $(this).text();
        var type = typeof textNode;
        var len = textNode.length;
        if($(this).is(':empty')){
            $(this).siblings('span.cw-value-two').css({"position": "relative", "left": "1em"});
        }
    });
```

Ok, so `textNode = ""`, `type = string` and `len = 1` - none of which is helpful in identifying an empty text node, since `a` has a type of string and length of 1.  The jQuery `.is(':empty')` is not working either.

So whow do you identify an empty text node in JQuery or plain ol' Javascript?

Comment: What does `$('span.cw-value-one').text().length` give you?

Comment: I'm confused, seems to be working for me, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/DGESk/

Comment: [I also beg to differ with your theory about jQuery's .empty() method.](http://jsfiddle.net/Fayky/)

Comment: Why is length 1? It is returning 0

Comment: Is it possible that in your real application you have `<span class="cw-value-one"> </span>`, with a blank between the opening and closing tags?

Answer (score 2):

You might be having white space in span use `trim()` to remove spaces within span around the text, if any.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/3QG6m/)**

```
  var textNode = $(this).text().trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

try checking by the length of the text.

```
$('span.cw-value-one').each(function(){
        var textNode = $(this).text();
        var type = typeof textNode;
        var len = textNode.length;

        if(len <= 0){
            $(this).siblings('span.cw-value-two').css({"position": "relative", "left": "1em"});
        }
    });​
```

I would also recommend trimming the text. If you want to trim the text please also be sure to see this about ie not liking trim. [.trim() in JavaScript not working in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308134/trim-in-javascript-not-working-in-ie)