# Why do I get the error IE Trim method isn't supported?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, trim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.trim() in JavaScript not working in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308134/trim-in-javascript-not-working-in-ie)

i have the following code but in IE it says that the trim method is not supported.

```
    for (var i = 0; i < here.length; i++) {

        if ($(here[i]).html().trim() == "")
            $(here[i]).parent().find('#content').css('width', '656px'),
            $(here[i]).parent().find('#content p').css('width', '430px');

        if ($(another[i]).html() != null) {
            if ($(another[i]).html().trim() == "")
                $(another[i]).parent().parent().css('display', 'none'),
                $('#sidemenu .heading').css('background', 'none');
        }
    }
```

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Older versions of Browsers (e.g. IE before version 9) don't have a `trim` method for strings implemented in their Javascript. You have these options:

- Use [`JQuery.trim`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) instead
- or define trim yourself - see the solutions pointed out in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498970/how-do-i-trim-a-string-in-javascript).