# Object doesn't support this property or method only on IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

This code run on Chrome, FF, Safari, IE9 but on IE8 i get this error:

> Message: Object doesn't support this property or method Line: 80 Char:
>   7 Code: 0

and this is what code its stopping on: (line 80 is on "return [" but the developer tool debugger highlights all this code below)

```
return [
    {
        title:'Edit',
        customClass:'actionEdit',
        action:{
            type:'getLink',
            url:'/admin/products/edit/'+data.id()+''
        }
    },
    {
        title:'Attaches',
        customClass:'actionAttaches',
        action:{
            type:'getLink',
            url:'/admin/attaches/index/product/'+data.id()+''
        }
    },
    {
        title:'Delete',
        customClass:'actionDelete',
        action:{
            type:'postLink',
            url:'/admin/products/delete/'+data.id()+'',
            confirm:'Are you sure you want to delete %s?',
            arg:$('#ProductAdminIndexList #'+data.id()+' .productId').text().trim()
        }
    }
];
```

I found others similar cases but i don't know why occur and how can solve this problem.

Comment: IE8 doesn't support some (non-standard but common) Javascript methods like `trim`.  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2308157/1001985

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solve it like this.

```
arg: $.trim($('#ProductAdminIndexList #'+data.id()+' .productId').text())
```

Comment: why the downvote? we already know that jQuery is being used, so why not use its trim function?

Answer (score 2):

I'm almost positive IE8 doesn't have a `trim()` method. jQuery however [provides an implementation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/), call it like `$.trim()` since it looks like you're already using jQuery.