# JQuery add class to wordpress nav menu depending on page href (not working in IE7/8)

Tags: jquery, wordpress, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, addclass

This script adds an active class to the current page in a wordpress generated nav menu (changes color & adds small background image arrow). However the document.ready function isn't working in IE 7 & 8.

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#menu-top-menu a').each(function(index) {
        if(this.href.trim() == window.location)
            $(this).addClass("active");
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.active {color: #41A2FF !important; background-image: url('navarrow.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 50% 3%; padding-top: 10px;}
```

I've googled this a lot and looked at a number of topics on this forum relating to similar IE <9 problems, and a few answers seemed to point to the window. and .href declarations but I couldn't seem to figure out exactly why It wasn't adding the class. Any help would be appreciated as my knowledge on jquery is limited.

-Thanks

...problem solved, .trim() wasn't working in IE : if($(this).attr("href") == window.location)

Comment: document.ready should work, so problem is somewhere else. Try $(this).attr("href").trim() instead.

Comment: didn't seem to work, tried as: ' if(this.attr("href").trim() == ' aswell

Comment: I guess the two values (probably window.location) is reported differently in IE7/8. Have you tried printing them to the console so you can see why the condition is not hitting?

Comment: ah sorry yes, in the console it was the .trim() that was not hitting.

this has worked:  if($(this).attr("href") == window.location)

Comment: additional : to get the .trim() working I could have also used the answer from this topic - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308134/trim-in-javascript-not-working-in-ie[link]

Comment: jQuery's .trim() does that. Therefore I suggested using it.

Comment: yes thank you, hence why I upped your original comment :) .. I ended up needing the trim for my sub menu active states, so this solution was the most appropriate.

I have another slight edit to this here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13528868/jquery-active-class-keep-class-on-main-nav-add-class-to-sub-nav[link] which is a slight problem

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer and accept that. This way your question won't remain in the "Unanswered" section.

Answer (score 0):

[To get .trim() working in ie7 & 8, if must be added in header:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308134/trim-in-javascript-not-working-in-ie)

```
if(typeof String.prototype.trim !== 'function') {
  String.prototype.trim = function() {
    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''); 
  }
}
```

Without using .trim():

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#menu-top-menu a').each(function(index) {
       if($(this).attr("href") == window.location)
            $(this).addClass("active");
    });
});
```

...however the second method limited me to only being able to apply the class to top level navigation