# Javascript to Trim spaces when enter value in text box

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am currently trying to show one text box value in another using javascript function

```
function fillTextbox() {
            var txtCompanyName = document.getElementById("txtCompanyName").value;
            document.getElementById("txtSecureSite").value = txtCompanyName;
        }
```

and i successfully done this but now i want to trim spaces when my user enters a name with spaces. Please help as i am new in javascript.

Comment: possible duplicate of [.trim() in JavaScript not working in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308134/trim-in-javascript-not-working-in-ie)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [string.trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim)

```
document.getElementById("txtSecureSite").value = txtCompanyName.toString().trim();
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim)

> Running the following code before any other code will create
>   String.trim if it's not natively available.

```
if(!String.prototype.trim) {
  String.prototype.trim = function () {
    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');
  };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can trim any string value like this:

```
" string ".trim(); // outputs: "string"
```

Based on: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim

Or use `jQuery.trim()` instead:

```
$.trim(" string "); // outputs: "string"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var orig = "   foo  ";
alert(orig.trim());
```

In your case:

```
var txtCompanyName = document.getElementById("txtCompanyName").value;
txtCompanyName  = txtCompanyName.toString().trim();
```

See [Trim()](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/trim.htm) in javascript

Answer (score 0):

Use `replace(/(^\s+|\s+$)/g, '')` to remove spaces from the begining and end of the string.

```
 function fillTextbox() {
                var txtCompanyName = document.getElementById("txtCompanyName").value;
                var company = txtCompanyName.replace(/(^\s+|\s+$)/g, '');
                document.getElementById("txtSecureSite").value = company;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
function fillTextbox() {
            var txtCompanyName = document.getElementById("txtCompanyName").value;
            var company = txtCompanyName.replace(/\s/g, "");
            document.getElementById("txtSecureSite").value = company;
        }
```

Comment: /\s/g will replace all the spaces. ^\s or \s$ will replace at the begining and end

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple, try this

```
var CompanyName = document.getElementById("txtCompanyName"),
CompanyNameTrimmed = CompanyName.value.trim(),
```

Comment: Already [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14892385/6670491). Btw, JavaScript don't use comma for line ends.

Comment: no wait. I used the comma so that i don't have to repeat the var again. 
It works like this, let a,b,c,d,e,f;