# Unable to add parameters to url

Tags: javascript

i want to add parameters to url, for that i have 2 textbox and a button, i can't figure out where am i stuck and is unable to add parameters to url 
here is my code:

HTML:

```html
Param Name: <input id="tbAddParam" type="text" /><br>
Param Value: <input id="tbAddParamValue" type="text" /><br>
<input onclick="javascript:AddParamter();" value="Add" type="button" />
```

JavaScript:

```
function AddParamter() {
    var new_url = AddUrlParameter(window.location.href, document.getElementById('tbAddParam').value, document.getElementById('tbAddParamValue').value);
    window.location.href = new_url;
}

function AddUrlParameter(a, b, c) {
    if (b.trim() == "") {
        alert("Parameter name should not be empty.");
        return a;
    }
    if (c.trim() == "") {
        alert("Parameter value should not be empty.");
        return a;
    }
    if (a.indexOf("?") == -1) {
        return a + "?" + b + "=" + c;
    }
    var d = a.split("?");
    if (d.length >= 2) {
        if (d[1].trim() == "") {
            return d[0] + "?" + b + "=" + c;
        }
        var e = d[1].split(/[&;]/g);
        for (var f = 0; f < e.length; f++) {
            var g = e[f]; var h = g.split("=");
            if (h.length >= 2) {
                if (h[0] == b) {
                    alert("Url Parameter with provided name already exists! Try Updating that Url Parameter.");
                    return a;
                }
            }
        }
        return a + "&" + b + "=" + c;
    }
}
```

Comment: what the the specific problem ?

Comment: What errors (if any) are you getting? In what way does this not work?

Comment: This is a JavaScript problem, no Java nor HTML nor JSP issue to solve =\

Comment: I retagged the question, as it seems to be unrelated to Java or JSP.

Comment: You can just copy/paste this code into a new HTML page and test it in Chrome or Firefox (with Firebug plugin) by pressing F12 key and using the JavaScript console to debug it.

Comment: there is no error but why my parameters are not adding i don't know new_url sometimes come out to be undefined

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: 2 textboxes values will be used as parameter name and parameter value

Comment: @lata I understand what you are trying to do. It may help us, and you, if you give your variables meaningful names, such as AddUrlParameter(url, parameter, value)

Comment: @rhughes: thankx for your valuable suggestion. i hope my question is clear now

Comment: I've tested your code and works for me (if the page ends in html, jsp or .something). What's the exact problem you're facing?

Comment: i have checked it in IE it is not working

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza, it works for me too.@lata, then whats your problem? Isnt it working in any particular browser like IE?

Comment: Maybe the problem is that your IE blocks the javascript for local execution (like if you were to use a XSS attack on localhost =\ ). I've tested the same page on IE9 and worked like a charm after enabling the script and ActiveX execution on localhost.

Comment: i am using eclipse IDE and it is not working, mu default browser is IE

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: so how to avoid that attack on localhost

Comment: The message pops up when you enter to IE. In IE9, it appears on the bottom part saying *Internet Explorer restricted this webpage from running scripts or ActiveX controls.* and on the right there's this option *Allow blocked content.*. Next time use at least two browsers to test your web pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments above:

I've tested your code and works for me (if the page ends in html, jsp or .something). This was tested using Chrome v25.

Later, I've tested on IE9 and it worked after enabling the script execution for local executed pages. A message pops up when you enter to IE. In IE9, it appears on the bottom part saying *Internet Explorer restricted this webpage from running scripts or ActiveX controls.* and on the right there's this option *Allow blocked content.*.

For IE backward compatibility, it seems that you should replace the `d[1].trim()` as stated in [james emanon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15061414/1065197).

As an advice, use at least two browsers to test your web pages. And yes, I highly recommend test on IE because it will give you a *good*(?) feedback for being so sensitive on scripting errors (it will arise so much errors that Chrome and Firefox cover for you).

Answer (score 1):

When running this in IE (I tested this in IE 10), you need to allow blocked content in order for the JavaScript to run. Otherwise the JavaScript will not be allowed to run. Luiggi Mendoza suggested the same for IE 9.

It is worth noting that this works fine in Chrome and FireFox without any user confirmation allowing JavaScript to run.

Answer (score 1):

IE doesn't like ".trim()". I tested in IE8 with IE8 compat mode, and your code didn't work because of trim. Though I imagine IE9 is fine (as noted by Luigi's confirmation).

use something like this instead:

```
strReplace=str.replace(/^\s+/,'').replace(/\s+$/,'');
```

You could get around it with something like:

```
function stripWhiteSpace(arg){
   if(arg.replace(/^\s+/,'').replace(/\s+$/,'') == ""){
      return true;
   }
}
```

then just call to it and pass your param

```
if (stripWhiteSpace(b))
```

Answer (score 1):

I support @rhughes's answer. But If you test this code in IE8(I was using this and your code was not working) and below, The HTML trim() wont work. As you have trim() in 3 places, you have to use the following.

```
if(typeof String.prototype.trim !== 'function') {
  String.prototype.trim = function() {
    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''); 
  }
}
```

or you can more easly use jQuery trim()

```
$.trim()
```

[refer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308134/trim-in-javascript-not-working-in-ie)

[refer 2](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/)