# Better way to validate the value of span

Tags: jquery

All, I am a newbie for jquery, I found sometimes I need write some code for validate the element value. like below.

```
var selectedLayOutIdx=$("#spanSelectedLayout").html();
if (selectedLayOutIdx!=undefined && selectedLayOutIdx!="") {
    alert("The value is null, please check it.");
    return;
} else {
    //keep going.
}
```

I found this code looks like verbose, I believe there must be a better way to make code work more fun in jquery. So far, I just haven't found it.

Please help me . thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you need to precisely define what the requirements are.
In your code you test against `undefined` jQuerys implementation of html never returns `undefined` so there's no reason to test against that. However there might or might not be reason to test against null

```
<div id="spanSelectedLayout">content</div>

var txt = $("#spanSelectedLayout").html() //txt will be "content"

<div id="spanSelectedLayout">    </div>

var txt = $("#spanSelectedLayout").html() //txt will be return "    "

<div id="spanSelectedLayout">    </div>

var txt = $.trim($("#spanSelectedLayout").html()) //txt will be return ""

<div id="spanSelectedLayout">    </div>

var txt = $("#spnSelectedLayout").html() //txt will be null
```

The latter is most likely to occur due to miss-spelling a selector, Ie a bug so you probably should treat that differently than "" or an all whitespace string. but "" and all whitespace HTML is semantically the same so you should probably treat those values alike which might then leading to

var selectedLayOutIdx=$.trim($("#spanSelectedLayout").html());
if( selectedLayOutIdx == "" ) {
   //is empty
}

However `$.trim(null)` returns `""` and not null so that will still hide the bug and you will therefor have to decide between the more concise code or something like this

```
var selectedLayOutIdx=$("#spanSelectedLayout").html();
if(selectedLayOutIdx == null) { throw "Invalid selector" }

if(  && $.trim(selectedLayOutIdx) == "" ) {
   //is empty
}
```

Comment: Best answer! I have to be responsible for the reviewer of the future.

Answer (score 3):

you could use [jQuery.trim()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/):

```
var selectedLayOutIdx=$.trim( $("#spanSelectedLayout").html() );
if( selectedLayOutIdx == "" ) {
  //its empty
}
```

OR

```
if( !$.trim($("#spanSelectedLayout").html()) ) {
     //its empty
}
```

Comment: @Joe.wang "better" is a matter of taste. It's better if short is good but not necessarily if understandability is what you aim at. `.html()` does not return a boolean so to be able to understand what it does you will have to be familiar with the falsy values of JS and in this case they does indeed make the second vresion different from the first. The first will only test for the empty string but `$trim(.html())` will return null if the selection is empty but an empty string if the selection in non-empty and has no html so the latter will hide a bug when you mistype the selector

Comment: @RuneFS Why did I get the message `undefined`? say you have the code like `$(document).ready(function () {
  alert($('#ddd').html());
            
        });`, I test it in firefox. the selector got nothing . `ddd` doesn't exist in page. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code to check value of span.

```
var selectedLayOutIdx=$("#spanSelectedLayout").text();
if(selectedLayOutIdx == ""){
  alert("Value is null")
}else{
  // Your code
}
```

UPDATED(shorter version):

```
if($("#spanSelectedLayout").text()){
  // code if text present
}
```

Comment: Hi, friend, I means I would like to find a shorter code. like Sudhir's answer. please review it .thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
var result=$("#spanSelectedLayout").html().replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '') 
if( result== "" ){

.
.
.
```

which is valid for all browsers .

[.trim()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308134/trim-in-javascript-not-working-in-ie) wont work in some versions of IE.

Comment: wow...I know this is a good answer , But I have trouble to understand regular expression .