# How to add and remove classes in Javascript without jQuery

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking for a fast and secure way to add and remove classes from an html element without jQuery.
It also should be working in early IE (IE8 and up).

Comment: Define *'early'*? See the [`classList` shim on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList#wrapper) For IE>7

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The following 3 functions work in browsers which don't support `classList`:

```
function hasClass(el, className)
{
    if (el.classList)
        return el.classList.contains(className);
    return !!el.className.match(new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + className + '(\\s|$)'));
}

function addClass(el, className)
{
    if (el.classList)
        el.classList.add(className)
    else if (!hasClass(el, className))
        el.className += " " + className;
}

function removeClass(el, className)
{
    if (el.classList)
        el.classList.remove(className)
    else if (hasClass(el, className))
    {
        var reg = new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + className + '(\\s|$)');
        el.className = el.className.replace(reg, ' ');
    }
}
```

https://jaketrent.com/post/addremove-classes-raw-javascript/

Comment: I always wonder why people add functionality for modern browsers? I mean isn't that code redundant if you want to support older browsers?

Comment: jongo45's answer is the best. [ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26736737/2968762)

Comment: @Abhi no it's not. His solution is for `IE10 onwards` and the questions states `IE8 and up`.

Answer (score 198):

Another approach to add the class to element using pure JavaScript

**For adding class:**

```
document.getElementById("div1").classList.add("classToBeAdded");
```

**For removing class:**

```
document.getElementById("div1").classList.remove("classToBeRemoved");
```

**Note:** but not supported in IE <= 9 or Safari <=5.0

Comment: Note: "[*(I) guess (in) IE 8 and up.*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26736587/how-to-add-and-remove-classes-in-js-without-jquery#comment42059466_26736587)"

Comment: @any way to add one and remove another in one statement?

Comment: @edddd yes! try element.classList.toggle,  examples on [MDN ClassList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Answer (score 30):

For future friendliness, I second the recommendation for classList with polyfill/shim: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#wrapper

```
var elem = document.getElementById( 'some-id' );
elem.classList.add('some-class'); // Add class
elem.classList.remove('some-other-class'); // Remove class
elem.classList.toggle('some-other-class'); // Add or remove class
if ( elem.classList.contains('some-third-class') ) { // Check for class
    console.log('yep!');
}
```

Answer (score 16):

[classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList) is available from IE10 onwards, use that if you can.

```
element.classList.add("something");
element.classList.remove("some-class");
```

Answer (score 16):

I'm baffled none of the answers here *prominently* mentions the incredibly useful [`DOMTokenList.prototype.toggle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle) method, which really simplifies alot of code.

E.g. you often see code that does this:

```js
if (element.classList.contains(className) {
  element.classList.remove(className)
} else {
  element.classList.add(className)
}
```

This can be replaced with a simple call to

```
element.classList.toggle(className)
```

What is also very helpful in many situations, if you are adding or removing a class name based on a condition, you can pass that condition as a second argument. If that argument is truthy, `toggle` acts as `add`, if it's falsy, it acts as though you called `remove`.

```
element.classList.toggle(className, condition) // add if condition truthy, otherwise remove
```

Answer (score 6):

To add class without JQuery just append `yourClassName` to your element `className`

`document.documentElement.className += " yourClassName";`

To remove class you can use `replace()` function

`document.documentElement.className.replace(/(?:^|\s)yourClassName(?!\S)/,'');`

Also as @DavidThomas mentioned you'd need to use the `new RegExp()` constructor if you want to pass class names dynamically to the replace function.

Comment: @George easely fixable by adding a space before and after className

Comment: @George In regular expressions, \b anchors the regex at a word boundary or the position between a word and a non-word character, or vice versa.

Comment: Note that you'd need to use the `new RegExp()` constructor if you want to pass class-names dynamically.

Comment: @DavidThomas Thanks for the remark, I include it in the answer if you don't mind

Comment: `\b` isn't sufficient in a RegExp because there are boundary characters that are valid in a class name. `/\bfoo\b/` will replace the first part of a class `"foo-bar"`.

Comment: @squint yes, you are right, it seems that it is necessary to use more complex regexp to deal with these cases...

Answer (score 4):

**Add & Remove Classes (tested on IE8+)**

Add trim() to IE (taken from: [.trim() in JavaScript not working in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308134/trim-in-javascript-not-working-in-ie))

```
if(typeof String.prototype.trim !== 'function') {
  String.prototype.trim = function() {
    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''); 
  }
}
```

Add and Remove Classes:

```
function addClass(element,className) {
  var currentClassName = element.getAttribute("class");
  if (typeof currentClassName!== "undefined" && currentClassName) {
    element.setAttribute("class",currentClassName + " "+ className);
  }
  else {
    element.setAttribute("class",className); 
  }
}
function removeClass(element,className) {
  var currentClassName = element.getAttribute("class");
  if (typeof currentClassName!== "undefined" && currentClassName) {

    var class2RemoveIndex = currentClassName.indexOf(className);
    if (class2RemoveIndex != -1) {
        var class2Remove = currentClassName.substr(class2RemoveIndex, className.length);
        var updatedClassName = currentClassName.replace(class2Remove,"").trim();
        element.setAttribute("class",updatedClassName);
    }
  }
  else {
    element.removeAttribute("class");   
  } 
}
```

Usage:

```
var targetElement = document.getElementById("myElement");

addClass(targetElement,"someClass");

removeClass(targetElement,"someClass");
```

A working JSFIDDLE:
http://jsfiddle.net/fixit/bac2vuzh/1/

Comment: <div class="parent-container" id="parent-container">
when i add the test class this happens:

<div class="parent-container test" id="parent-container">

then i remove the class

<div class="paent-container" id="parent-container">

it deletes the "r" in parent-container

Comment: Added a working JSFIDDLE - if it keeps happening, let me know on which browser & version

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
  const element = document.querySelector('#elementId');
  if (element.classList.contains("classToBeRemoved")) {
    element.classList.remove("classToBeRemoved");

  }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also do

```
elem.classList[test ? 'add' : 'remove']('class-to-add-or-remove');
```

Instead of

```
if (test) {
    elem.classList.add('class-to-add-or-remove');
} else {
    elem.classList.remove('class-to-add-or-remove');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm using this simple code for this task:

**CSS Code**

```
.demo {
     background: tomato;
     color: white;
}
```

**Javascript code**

```
function myFunction() {
    /* Assign element to x variable by id  */
    var x = document.getElementById('para);

    if (x.hasAttribute('class') {      
        x.removeAttribute('class');     
    } else {
        x.setAttribute('class', 'demo');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Updated JS Class Method

The `add` methods do not add duplicate classes and the `remove` method only removes class with exact string match.

```
const addClass = (selector, classList) => {
  const element = document.querySelector(selector);
  const classes = classList.split(' ')
  classes.forEach((item, id) => {
    element.classList.add(item)
  })
}

const removeClass = (selector, classList) => {
  const element = document.querySelector(selector);
  const classes = classList.split(' ')
  classes.forEach((item, id) => {
    element.classList.remove(item)
  })
}

addClass('button.submit', 'text-white color-blue') // add text-white and color-blue classes
removeClass('#home .paragraph', 'text-red bold') // removes text-red and bold classes
```

Answer (score 0):

When you remove RegExp from the equation you leave a less "friendly" code, but it still can be done with the (much) less elegant way of *split()*.

```
function removeClass(classString, toRemove) {
    classes = classString.split(' ');
    var out = Array();
    for (var i=0; i<classes.length; i++) {
        if (classes[i].length == 0) // double spaces can create empty elements
            continue;
        if (classes[i] == toRemove) // don't include this one
            continue;
        out.push(classes[i])
    }
    return out.join(' ');
}
```

This method is a lot bigger than a simple *replace()* but at least it can be used on older browsers. And in case the browser doesn't even support the *split()* command it's relatively easy to add it using prototype.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone needs to toggle class on click and remove on other elements in JS only. You can try to do following :

```
var accordionIcon = document.querySelectorAll('.accordion-toggle');
//add only on first element, that was required in my case 
accordionIcon[0].classList.add('close');
for (i = 0; i < accordionIcon.length; i++) {

accordionIcon[i].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
for (i = 0; i < accordionIcon.length; i++) {

if(accordionIcon[i] !== event.target){
accordionIcon[i].classList.remove('close');
}
event.target.classList.toggle("close");
}

})
}
```