# How to remove a div by class with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to remove a div by class with JavaScript from an existing website.

```
<div id="application-form">
   <div class="show-pl">Test</div
</div>
```

Comment: Write to the console: `document.querySelector('#application-form .show-pl').className = '';`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add and remove classes in Javascript without jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26736587/how-to-add-and-remove-classes-in-javascript-without-jquery)

Comment: Please clarify if you want to remove "div by class" or "class from a div"? Question title differs from the question text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `removeAttribute('class')`

```js
document.querySelector('.show-pl').removeAttribute('class');
```

```html
<div id="application-form">
  <div class="show-pl">Test</div>
</div>
```

If you want to remove element with required class, use `document.querySelector('.show-pl').remove();`

```js
document.querySelector('.show-pl').remove();
```

```html
<div id="application-form">
  <div class="show-pl">Test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @LauraV6 - Or if you need to support obsolete browsers like IE: The old way was to call [`removeChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild) on the parent: `var element = document.querySelector('.show-pl'); element.parentNode.removeChild(element);`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove class, just use listClass.remove('classname') like this:

`document.querySelector('your-selector').classList.remove('classname-to-remove')`