# I'm trying to figure out how to use addEventListener to show only when the user selects certain option

Tags: javascript, html, forms

```
 var AddType = document.getElementById("addressType.form-control");
            var otherAdd = document.getElementById("otherAddType.form-control");

            AddType.addEventListener("show", function(){
            if (AddType.value = "other"){
            otherAdd.setAttribute("class", "show");
            }else {
            otherAdd.setAttribute("class", "hidden");
            }
            }, false);
```

Comment: [Deprecated `show event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/show_event) .Most of  the major browser not supported

Comment: add the click event listener to the address type selector then add and remove the classes from classList. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26736587/how-to-add-and-remove-classes-in-javascript-without-jquery