# How do I trim() a string in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Is there an angular specific way?  If not, should I use the built in jquery to do it?  If I should use the built in jquery how do I get to the trim() function without using $ (or is that necessary)?

Edit - Yes I know about str.trim().  Sorry.  I need this to work in IE 8

Edit - As far as this question being a duplicate, I am asking specifically how to do this in angular where the answer referenced explains how to do it in javascript, node and jquery.  Is there a way to do it using the built in jquery in angular?

Edit - Apparently the answer is "AngularJS doesn't do this"

Comment: [trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) is a built in method on the String prototype, supported on most browsers. The MDN link provides a polyfill

Comment: Your edit is very unfair to the people who have already answered. You should include that kind of stipulation at the offset.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trim string in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/498970/trim-string-in-javascript)

Comment: Qantas 94 Heavy - yes the jquery example is there but I didn't know if that would work in angular since the $ is overridden.

Comment: I agree with @CodingIntrigue, your edits are unfair to others who have answered. also, while angular does not provide an out of the box solution IMHO a filter is the angular way of doing this.

Answer (score 26):

Why don't you simply use JavaScript's ***[trim()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp)***:

```
str.trim() //Will work everywhere irrespective of any framework.
```

For compatibility with `<IE9` use:

```
if(typeof String.prototype.trim !== 'function') {
  String.prototype.trim = function() {
    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''); 
  }
}
```

Found it ***[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2308157/3894168)***

Comment: Well...not everywhere...e.g. in <IE9 :)

Comment: http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#String.prototype.trim. Only not in Strict mode in IE9

Comment: @Slartibartfast. Found a solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2308157/3894168). Also updated in code.

Comment: This works and I am aware of this solution, but I was after an angular specific way, possibly using the built in jquery.  It appears this doesn't exist.

Comment: @Slartibartfast. There is no inbuilt method in angular for this. you can however use the other solution which will work regardless of browser versions.

Answer (score 20):

If you need only *display* the trimmed value then I'd suggest against manipulating the original string and using a [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) instead.

```
app.filter('trim', function () {
    return function(value) {
        if(!angular.isString(value)) {
            return value;
        }  
        return value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''); // you could use .trim, but it's not going to work in IE<9
    };
});
```

And then

```
<span>{{ foo | trim }}</span>
```

Answer (score 13):

use trim() method of javascript  after all angularjs is also a javascript framework and it is not necessary to put $ to apply trim()

for example

```
var x="hello world";
x=x.trim()
```

Comment: Earlier in question it was not mention that it is not working for you in IE ,so that now you can use str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ' ');

Answer (score 6):

I insert this code in my tag and it works correctly:

```
ng-show="!Contract.BuyerName.trim()" >
```

Comment: why is this downvoted? Worked great for me and seems to be the simplest solution.

Answer (score 1):

JS .trim() is supported in basically everthing, except IE 8 and below.

If you want it to work with that, then, you can use JQuery, but it'll need to be <2.0.0 (as they removed support for IE8 in the 2.x.x line).

Your other option, if you care about IE7/8 (As you mention earlier), is to add trim yourself:

```
if(typeof String.prototype.trim !== 'function') {
  String.prototype.trim = function() {
    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''); 
  }
}
```

Comment: From this and other responses I am gathering that there is not an angularjs specific way of handling this.