# How to Trim variable in View Using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The value of {{bb}} is  "9.00 to 10.00"

I Want to display only 9

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I trim() a string in angularjs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30506300/how-do-i-trim-a-string-in-angularjs)

Comment: Thank You ... mfathy00 I got solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to display only the first character then the simplest is to use `[0]`:

```
{{ bb[0] }}
```

However, if your goal is to display hour portion of the string then you could do something like this:

```
{{ bb.split('.')[0] }}
```

and for `12.00 to 13.00` it would print `12` as expected.

Comment: Thank you for your reply i got solution form second one .. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can use **`ng-blur`** with **`Math.round`** like

```
ng-blur="number = Math.round(number)"
```

You can also use  filter [components in ng / number](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number)