# Getting data from php, sending directly to javascript and using Comparison Operators with the data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, operators

Let's say in this case, it needs to be done this way...

I have a menu bar to the left side of the screen that loads a default initial "position", whatever menu set to 1 loads the page with it open, whatever set to 0 loads the page closed.

This website works with subtopics, pretty much this way:

Example: "http://localhost/?subtopic=latestnews".

And all the subtopics are divided between the topics (menus).

**What I'm trying to do with this menu is:** Get the page to identify the current subtopic page, get its topic and when the page is loaded, only that menu will be open.

Example: Menus | News.........| Support

........Subtopics....| latestnews.| contactus

When I open the page latestnews, only the menu news loads opened, and when I open contactus, only the support menu loads opened.

I already have a function returning the topic value from any subtopic loaded, and I'm being able to send it to the javascript and `alert()` it already, but when I use comparison operators in the javascript to change the default values (1 : 0) it always returns 0, no matter what.

**OBS.:** When I manually edit the values (1 : 0) without the operators the menu works properly.

Here is the JavaScript part:

```
function InitializePage() {
  LoadMenu();
}
function LoadMenu() {
  document.getElementById("submenu_" + activeSubmenuItem).style.color = "white";
  document.getElementById("ActiveSubmenuItemIcon_" + activeSubmenuItem).style.visibility = "visible";
  var news, aboutgatia, gameguides, library, community, events, forum, account, support, shop;
  var div = document.getElementById("topic_finder"); //here is the div with the topic name to compare
  var myData = div.textContent;
  if (self.name.lastIndexOf("&") == -1) {
    news = ((myData == "news") ? 1 : 0); //Here the comparison operator that is not working and I can't figure out why
    aboutgatia = 0;
    gameguides = 0;
    library = 0;
    community = 0;
    events = 0;
    forum = 0;
    account = 0;
    support = 0;
    shop = 0;
    alert(myData);
    self.name = "news=" + news + "&aboutgatia=" + aboutgatia + "&gameguides=" + gameguides + "&library=" + library + "&community=" + community + "&events=" + events + "&forum=" + forum + "&account=" + account + "&support=" + support + "&shop=" + shop + "&";
  }
  FillMenuArray();
  InitializeMenu();
}
```

And here is the PHP/HTML part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">InitializePage();</script></div>
<div id="topic_finder" style="display: none;">
  <?php
    $topic_output = getTopic($subtopic); //Here is that function I mentioned before
    echo htmlspecialchars($topic_output);
  ?>
</div>
```

Comment: So `var myData = div.textContent;` does not return "news" but something else. Try   `var myData = div.textContent.trim();` and console log it to see if it is what you expect - also this would work too `news = myData == "news"`

Comment: Wow it worked!!! What did `trim();` do?

Comment: remove leading and trailing space from the string. Note .trim() needs a polyfill for IE<9: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim

Comment: thank you I thought it was returning news to the javascript with ( " )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are not actually showing the string, why not just do

```
news = "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($topic_output); ?>" == "news";
```

or

```
document.getElementById("submenu_<?php echo htmlspecialchars($topic_output); ?>")....
```

Your current code will look like this in the browser

```
<div id="topic_finder" style="display: none;">
whitepace  news whitespace
</div>
```

So `var myData = div.textContent;` does not return "news" but something else. Try [trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) to remove leading and trailing spaces

```
var myData = div.textContent.trim();
```

and console log it to see if it is what you expect - then this would work too

```
news = myData == "news"
```

without the ternary

Note .trim() needs a polyfill for IE<9:

```
if (!String.prototype.trim) {
  String.prototype.trim = function () {
    return this.replace(/^[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+|[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+$/g, '');
  };
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308134/trim-in-javascript-not-working-in-ie should do the trick

Answer (score -1):

just parse your input to proper format, here you are comparing with string so add following lines in your code.

```
var div = document.getElementById("topic_finder");
var myData = div.textContent;
myData = String(myData);
```

...do further functions...