# Swipebox plugin errors in IE7 (Object doesn't support property or method 'trim' )

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins

Swipebox jquery plugin gives error in IE7 when any attached image is click (to show it in popup modal box). The error specifically points to `jquery.swipebox.js` in *Line:815*, saying:

> Object doesn't support property or method 'trim'

On *Line: 815* the code is as below:

```
loadMedia : function ( src, callback ) {
    // Inline content
    if ( src.trim().indexOf('#') === 0 ) {       // <=== Line:815
        callback.call(...)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some search I came across following solution which worked very well for me.

[.trim() in JavaScript not working in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308134/trim-in-javascript-not-working-in-ie#)

I added following piece of code just before the `if` condition:

```
if(typeof String.prototype.trim !== 'function') {
    String.prototype.trim = function() {
        return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''); 
    }
}
```